# Is it better to open/close a file many times or once and for all?

Tags: file, security

If I have to deal with a file many times in a script. Basically if I need to read it at the beginning of my script, and write it at the end. Is it better to do:

```
f = open("myfile", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
# ...
# Edit some lines
# ...
f = open("myfile", "w")
f.write(lines)
f.close()
```

Or:

```
f = open("myfile", "r+")
lines = f.readlines()
# ...
# Edit some lines
# ...
f.seek(0)
f.truncate()
f.write(lines)
f.close()
```

By "better" I mean "more secure". I think that both scripts have a security breach if the process is stopped while the file is still opened, but this has less chances to happen in the former script.

I don't think the languages matters but I mainly use Python.

Answer (score 1):

Usually one wants to `open` and `close` a file only once. Main reason is performance.
If you are concerned about 'security', you mention an unexpected end of the script, which I would call 'stability concerns' instead, then `flush` your script each time you have written into it but don't close it. Then in case your script bails out the written content still is safe and the file is automatically closed during the cleanup.

An advantage of that strategy is also that you have to check the success of accessing and opening the script only once instead of having to do all that again and again all through your script.

Comment: Actually my script is intended to be executed in SUID mode (so with temporary extra rights). Doesn't it allow the user to somehow do anything he want with the opened file?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the question, sorry. Apart from that: obviously the user can do anything he wants with it as long as it is granted to him by the rights management. So he can delete the file if he has the (temporary) right to do so. But that is completely irrelevant for the questin you asked, whether it is better to open/close the file once or multiple times. Your script certainly won't get more secure if you only keep it open for short periods.

Comment: To be fair he is asking which one is more secure and I agree with you that one method is no better than the other. Maybe just put it in a try catch so it gets closed cleanly if there's an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping aside all the other factors like

- Securing the channel of data transfer
- Checking the file permissions
- Checking the file attributes so that application can trust the file
- Secure Design
- Time of Check Versus Time of Use for temporary files

  etc etc

If you want to pickup preference between just two
*opening the file once or opening the file multiple times for a operation.*

My pick would be open the file only once. The more times you open a file the more time you will have to go through ensuring security checks.